# How to link storyboard elements to view controller in swift using ctrl+drag

Tags: xcode, swift

This is literally day 1 of programming and I can't even link my UI elements to the view controller using ctrl+dragging motion. What am I doing wrong? I want to attach screenshot but Stack Overflow won't let me!

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_outlet_connections

Comment: You can use http://postimage.org/ to post an image

Comment: make sure you set the class of your ViewController in your storyboard file to the class of your .swift file that you are trying to control drag to. So if you are trying to link your storyboard elements to a `MyViewController.swift` file, make sure that your ViewController in your storyboard is set as a MyViewController. You can check this by clicking the yellow circle at the top bar of your viewcontroller, going to the Identity Inspector, and checking that the Class field is MyViewController

Comment: Thank you all so much for commenting! Here is the link to what my environment looks like http://postimg.org/image/r5gdsi919/ 

@ad121 It looks like my viewcontroller is set, but I still can't ctrl+drag from viewcontroller in the left hand panel to my labels.

Comment: Also, @ad121 I am using a Mac and not Windows computer... should I be pressing a different button and dragging?

Comment: You aren't supposed to cntrl+drag from the left panel. You open up Assistant editor and cntrl+drag from your label in the storyboard (shown on one screen of the Assistant Editor) into the code for ViewController.swift (shown on the other screen of the assistant editor).